# Oracle password expire warning not displaying

Tags: oracle, change-password

I'm usually prompted with a message saying that the password for the user is going to expire in x days.  I get this message when using SQL developer or `SQL*Plus`. Currently I log into `SQL*Plus` as the system user and I run the following script:

```
select username, expiry_date from dba_users 
/
```

It shows my user and that the password will expire tomorrow.  I don't get a message saying that it will expire.  If I didn't randomly check I would never have known and my systems would have went down.

Is there a way to turn this feature on?

Answer (score 0):

The password will expire at `expiry_date`. However if the PROFILE of this user has a `PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME` defined then user will get notification like "Your password will expire on ...". Otherwise password expires with immediate effect and the user has to change his password.

Comment: PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME is set to 7 for the default profile.  I'm just worried that something else is going on and is the reason I didn't get a message warning me.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you connecting to the database?  If you connect `as sysdba` Oracle won't really connect as the specified user, it will connect as `SYS`.  In that case Oracle may bypass normal database authentication and will rely on the operating system.  Even if the username is expired you can still connect `as sysdba`.

Comment: Hi Jon,  I have to user accounts that are used as part of my websites and when I would log onto the database in SQL developer a message usually pops up and says it will expire in the next n days.   What I did was setup a reminder every 6 months to double check and make sure it hasn't expired.